# java.util.BitSet -- set() doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitset

Am I missing something painfully obvious?  Or does just nobody in the world actually use java.util.BitSet?

The following test fails:

```
@Test
public void testBitSet() throws Exception {
    BitSet b = new BitSet();
    b.set(0, true);
    b.set(1, false);
    assertEquals(2, b.length());
}
```

It's really unclear to me why I don't end up with a BitSet of length 2 and the value 10.  I peeked at the source for java.util.BitSet, and on casual inspection it seems to fail to make sufficient distinction between a bit that's been set false and a bit that has never been set to any value...

(Note that explicitly setting the size of the BitSet in the constructor has no effect, e.g.:

```
BitSet b = new BitSet(2);
```

Comment: "Or does just nobody in the world actually use java.util.BitSet?" ... yea, right, pull the other one - its got bells on it!

Comment: @Stephen which other one? ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People do use `BitSet`; however, they use it for something other than what you intend.  It's probably best to think of `BitSet` as a very compact, memory-efficient form of `Set<Integer>` that has the peculiar property that you can't put negative numbers into it.

It's very common with `BitSet`s to use them in the pattern of

```
for (int id = set.nextSetBit(0); id >= 0; id = set.nextSetBit(id + 1)) {
  // do stuff to a set index
}
```

after you do something to fill them up.  This is equivalent to iterating over the elements of the `Set`.

Comment: Good explanation.  Basically, it seems BitSet isn't really well-suited to representing a fixed-length bitfield (or bit array).

Comment: Well, for a *fixed* length, if you don't rely on the BitSet to maintain the length for you it's okay.  If you want the BitSet to handle length for you, you'll be disappointed.

Answer (score 10):

You highest bit set (as in "set to 1") is Bit 0. So the length should be 1.

See the [JavaDoc for length](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length%28%29):

> **public int length()**
>
> Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one. Returns zero if the BitSet contains no set bits.

Maybe you're looking for [size](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size%28%29) although it's possible that might be *higher* than two if bits are allocated at a certain resolution (say 16 bit boundaries)?

Comment: ZZ, I cleaned it up to make sure it was clear (and +1'ed it), hope you don't mind. Given that I initially misunderstood "set" as "has been set to anything", lesser mortals may also have that problem :-)

Answer (score 4):

This puzzled me too, not sure of the rationale behind BitSet's current rather unexpected functionality. However since it's not final, we can use some embrace and extend tactics and do the following to get a fixed BitSet with length semantics as expected:

```
import java.util.BitSet;

/**
 * Variation of BitSet which does NOT interpret the highest bit synonymous with
 * its length.
 *
 * @author casper.bang@gmail.com
 */
public class FixedBitSet extends BitSet{

    int fixedLength;

    public FixedBitSet(int fixedLength){
        super(fixedLength);
        this.fixedLength = fixedLength;
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return fixedLength;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that the bitset is backed by a long[], the minimum size is 64 (because 1 long is 64 bits). The size gets incremented by a multiple of 64 and for some reason, they have not maintained the # of bits you intended to represent when you use the constructor that takes an int.

Answer (score 1):

// Abhay Dandekar

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class TestBitSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
        System.out.println("State 0 : " + bitSet.size() + " : " + bitSet.length() );

        bitSet.set(0, true);
        bitSet.set(1, true);
        System.out.println("State 1 : " + bitSet.size() + " : " + bitSet.length() );

        bitSet.set(2, false);
        bitSet.set(3, false);
        System.out.println("State 2 : " + bitSet.size() + " : " + bitSet.length() );

        bitSet.set(4, true);
        System.out.println("State 3 : " + bitSet.size() + " : " + bitSet.length() );

    }
}
```

A simple java program to show what happens inside. Some points to note :

1. BitSet is backed by a long
2. All the default values are false
3. While returning the length, it returns the index+1 of the highest "true" value in the set.

The output below should be able to explain itself :

```
State 0 : 64 : 0

State 1 : 64 : 2

State 2 : 64 : 2

State 3 : 64 : 5
```

So points to conclude :

1. Do not use the length to conclude the no of bits modified
2. Can be used in scenarios like bloom filters. More on bloom filters can be googled .. ;)

Hope this helps

Regards,

Abhay Dandekar

Answer (score 0):

Good Casper! Your small improvement should indeed have been present in the original BitSet java def! I also suggest this (append() and concat() are useful for various usages)

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class fixBitSet extends BitSet {

  public int fsize = 0;

  public void set(int k, boolean value) {
    if (k >= fsize)
      fsize = k + 1;
    super.set(k, value);
  }

  public void append(fixBitSet bs) {
    for (int k = 0; k < bs.fsize; k++)
      super.set(fsize + k, bs.get(k));
    fsize += bs.fsize;
  }

  public static fixBitSet concat(fixBitSet[] vbs) {
    final fixBitSet bs = new fixBitSet();
    for (fixBitSet xbs : vbs)
      bs.append(xbs);
    return (bs);
  }

}
```