# BitSet length returning 0

Tags: java, bitset

I'm using a BitSet to represent a time series of data. For example, the first bit represents day 1, the second bit represents day 2, etc.

I am confused when I run the following code because it always returns the length as 0:

```
BitSet a = new BitSet();
for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
   a.set(i, false);
}
System.out.println(a.length());
```

After some playing around I see its because the values are all false. I set the bit to zero so I would assume it would count in the length and I need it to count. Is there a way to get the count including false and true?

Comment: Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854098/java-util-bitset-set-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length--): *"Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one. **Returns zero if the BitSet contains no set bits**."*

Comment: Actually, why do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

Class BitSet have a [constructor with the desired number of bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#BitSet-int-).

> Creates a bit set whose initial size is large enough to explicitly
>   represent bits with indices in the range 0 through nbits-1. All bits
>   are initially false.

[BitSet.size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size--)

> Returns the number of bits of space actually in use by this BitSet to
>   represent bit values. The maximum element in the set is the size - 1st
>   element.

[BitSet.cardinality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#cardinality--)

> Returns the number of bits set to true in this BitSet.

BitSet is a compacted set of bit, it seems it's not your need because you have to known the number of bits set to true or false.

My proposal:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      final List<Boolean> bs = new ArrayList<>( 100 );
      for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
         bs.add( Boolean.FALSE );
      }
      System.err.println( bs.size());
      bs.set( 7, Boolean.TRUE );
      System.err.println( bs.size());
      bs.set( 42, Boolean.TRUE );
      System.err.println( bs.size());
   }
}
```

This program echoes 100, 3 times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I looked at both these methods and they don't return the number of bits I set. Size() will return 128 in my example and cardinality will return 0 since no bits are set. I am looking to get how many bits I have set to either false or true. So in my example I am looking to return 100.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using only `BitSet` itself - I looked at the implementation, and it simply doesn't store what you want. I can only point out solutions you probably already have in mind:

1) Keep track of the length yourself

2) Use `BitSet` from some library (I've found this: https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simul/ssj-2/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/util/BitVector.html)

3) Extend `BitSet` (as pointed out in comments, not the best idea):

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class MyBitSet extends BitSet {
  int trueLength = 0;

  @Override
  public void set(int bitIndex) {
    trueLength = Math.max(trueLength, bitIndex + 1);
    super.set(bitIndex);
  }

  @Override
  public void clear(int bitIndex) {
    trueLength = Math.max(trueLength, bitIndex + 1);
    super.clear(bitIndex);
  }

  /* Maybe overload something else... */

  /* Or override length */
  int getTrueLength() {
    return trueLength;
  }
}
```

Comment: You missed about a dozen overloads for #3.

Comment: I think only `set(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` and `clear(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`.

Comment: No, there's 3 `clear()` overloads, and 4 `set()` overloads, and `flip()` and `and()` and `or()` etc. etc. And who's to say what they'll add in the next version. This is a classic misuse of inheritance.

Comment: These `set`-s call this `set`, so it's fine. For others - agreed, you should override them too.

Comment: Fair point. But that's an implementation detail. There's no guarantee another (parallel or future) implementation will do the same.

Comment: I see, agreed. And yeah, delegation would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to contain any method for what you're expecting.

Length returns the size of the BitSet for the last "true" value it has... so:

```
false, false, false, true, false, false
```

Will return a length of 4.

Size in the other hand, returns the list max size, it start with 128, but if you pass this mark, it will auto-increase its size.

So, I don't know the actual scenario in which you want to use this, but maybe you could do it with a simple `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> Is there a way to get the count including false and true?

Answer:

No, not from `BitSet`, not reliably! ..you can issue `BitSet.size()`, which will give you:

> the number of bits currently in this bit set

but `size()` (value) won't change, as long as you do `bitSet.set(i, false)` resp. `bitSet.clear(i)` ..for any `i`.

...only when `i >= size()` and `bitSet.set(i/*, true*/)`, it will have effect on (the value of) `size()`.

---

And even if you do:

```
final int nbits = 1000; 
BitSet bs = new BitSet(nbits);
```

(initialize your bit set with "non default size"), then it is guaranteed, that `bs.size() >= nbits`, but not `bs.size() == nbits`.